# Android doesn't show on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I've been trying to debug my phone and at first it worked but later when I disconnected the phone and tried later it stopped working, it just wasn't showing up and the question: "Do you grant permission...." stopped showing up too. I also checked USB debugging is on I don't know what could cause this problem, it worked before why not again?

I checked if USB debugging is on, I also watched youtube videos on how to fix this and it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Sounds stupid but have you tried disonnecting the phone and trying again? Restaring the phone/computer might also help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**:
I recommend disabling and enabling USB debugging again

**Second**:
Try to revoke USB Debugging authorizations

**Third**:
If the problem still persists, Try to play with those options [FIRST, SECOND]

Comment: Have you tried to disconnect the phone and try again the steps above?